# Ubuntu 20.04 hangs after sent to Suspend mode

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on Lenovo Thinkpad P1 (and using Grub to dual boot between Windows and Linux on two physically separate SSD drives).

Recently I let the system install some updates. After that, I'm not able to send the machine to Suspend mode. I am not using the lid to suspend it since I use external monitors. I tried the UI command and also command line `systemctl suspend`. Both don't work:

- screen goes blank
- the laptop light on the power button is still on
- I hear the fan running
- I can't wake the system
- I have to hard reset the system by pressing the power button for 5 seconds

What could be wrong? Which logs should I look first? What to search for in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this one by changing my NVIDIA display driver:

`Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers`

I switched from "Using X.Org xserver-xorg-video-nouveau" to "Using NVIDIA driver nvidida-driver-510".